# How can I get LoL Replay to work nicely with my Norton 360?

Tags: anti-virus, norton-antivirus, norton-360

Norton 360 thinks that some of the files required for my LoL Replay to work are viruses.

THe LoL Replay says I should add the file path for the program into my antivirus to allow it as an exception.

Norton 360 doesn't allow file path entries, it wants you to except specific files. However, when I look up the files to except them, it gives me almost NO details on which file is which, so I basically have no way of knowing if I'm excepting an actual virus or the file I need for LoL Replay to work...

[image]

[image]

Risk Details tells me nothing.

Comment: I wouldn't use Norton in the first place^^ but I think the question isn't offtopic, since most likely people who play LoL will have expierence with this.

Comment: @Jacimovski i understand that much of teh community hates norton but I like it, its always done right by me, and since I've bought it, im stickin with it.

Comment: To use Norton, you must pay a yearly subscription renewal fee. I'm not sure that it's worthwhile for you to continue to pay this fee. You can switch to [Windows Defender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Defender) at no charge — you paid for it when you bought your computer, and there are no subscription renewal costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution!

- Disable Norton 360 Auto-Protect
- Uninstall the LoL Replay Program
- Reinstall the LoL Replay Program
- Go into the Lol Replay Installation Directory and find the file before Norton 360 grabs it and changes its name to something ambiguous, right click it, and except it from the antivirus manually that way.
- Re-enable Auto Protect.

## Voila!

Answer (score 4):

Simple fix: Don't use norton. Their database of viruses is full of false-positives.

Desired fix for you: Select replay.* (meaning select all the items with the name replay in front) and add them as exceptions

Also, clicking **risk details** will give you more information

Comment: how do i know their all the correct file? Is there some way to confirm? Risk details gives me nothing usefull, I'll include that in another screenshot

Comment: @Ender I've already told you. **Select replay.* (meaning select all the items with the name replay in front) and add them as exceptions**

Comment: Read my edit and you'll find out

Comment: +1 for "Don't use Norton". I used to have a LOT of problems with my antivirus - then I switched (to AVG). Haven't had a problem since...

Comment: I recommend switching to MSE.